# how to update my tables inside the database using the GUI

Tags: java, swing, sql-update

Good Day!
I am having a problem with my Update function. 
I have a table in mysql. namely tblClientInfo, tblbusinessinfo, tblbusinesssituation, tblledger. the table tblClientInfo has the primary key, CLIENTID. the other 3 tables uses this clientid as foreign key. The problem is, whenever i ran my program and update unfilled textboxes in the User interface, i cannot update. only the infos inside the tblClientInfo are updated but not the other table. but i can update if the information already existed on the database. but if i save new info about a new client, only tblclient is saved and when i try to update , it doesn;t work...

here's my code for SAVE:

```
private void cmdSaveMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)  
{                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql = "insert into tblClientInfo (ClientID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, BirthPlace, BirthDate, "
                + "Status, ResAddress, EmploymentQuery, HomeNo, ResidenceType) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

    String sql2 = "insert into tblBusinessInfo (tblBusinessInfo.ClientID, MarketID, StallNo, Location, BusinessTelNo, YearStarted, "
                + "OtherBusinessQuery, MonthlyIncome, CarQuery, CarBrand, MortgagedQuery, PBalance) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    String sql3 = "insert into tblBusinessSituation (tblBusinessSituation.ClientID, MerchandiseID, StockValue, "
                + "LowestSale, AverageSale) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    String sql4 = "insert into tblledger (tblledger.ClientID, MarketID, LoanAmount, DateStarted, DailyPay, Expiry) "
                + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try 
    {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        //===================================Client Information Layer=======================================
        pst.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtLastName.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtFirstName.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtMiddleName.getText());  
        pst.setString(5, (String) comboGender.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(6, txtBirthPlace.getText());
        if(txtBirthDate.getText().isEmpty())
            pst.setString(7, null);
        else
            pst.setString(7, txtBirthDate.getText());
        pst.setString(8, (String) comboStatus.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(9, txtAddress.getText());
        pst.setString(10, (String) comboEmploymentQuery.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if(txtHomeNo.getText().isEmpty())
            pst.setString(11, null);
        else
            pst.setString(11, txtHomeNo.getText());
        pst.setString(12, (String) comboResidency.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.execute();
        //System.out.println("Nasave ang sql ? : "+pst.execute());

        UpdateJTable();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } 


    try
    {
        pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

        //===================================Buainess Information   Layer======================================
        pst2.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
        pst2.setString(2, (String) comboMarket.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
        if(txtStallNo.getText().isEmpty())
            pst2.setString(3, null);

        else
            pst2.setString(3, txtStallNo.getText());
        pst2.setString(4, txtLocation.getText());
        if(txtBusinessNo.getText().isEmpty())
            pst2.setString(5, null);
        else
            pst2.setString(5, txtBusinessNo.getText());
        if(txtYearStarted.getText().isEmpty())
            pst2.setString(6, null);
        else
            pst2.setString(6, txtYearStarted.getText());
        pst2.setString(7, (String) comboOtherBusinessQuery.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if(txtMonthlyIncome.getText().isEmpty())
            pst.setString(8, null);
        else
            pst2.setString(8, txtMonthlyIncome.getText());
        pst2.setString(9, (String) comboCar.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst2.setString(10, txtBrand.getText());
        pst2.setString(11, (String) comboMortgaged.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if(txtPBalance.getText().isEmpty())
            pst2.setString(12, null);
        else
            pst2.setString(12, txtPBalance.getText());
        pst2.execute();
        // System.out.println("Nasave ang sql2 ? : "+ pst2.execute());

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    try
    {
        pst3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);

        pst3.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
        pst3.setString(2, (String) comboMerchandise.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
        if(txtValueOfStocks.getText().isEmpty())
            pst3.setString(3, null);
        else
            pst3.setString(3, txtValueOfStocks.getText());
        if(txtLowestSale.getText().isEmpty())
            pst3.setString(4, null);
        else
            pst3.setString(4, txtLowestSale.getText());
        if(txtAveSale.getText().isEmpty())
            pst3.setString(5, null);
        else
            pst3.setString(5, txtAveSale.getText());        
        pst3.execute();
        //System.out.println("Nasave ang sql3 ? : "+ pst3.execute());

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);      
    }  

    try
    {  

        pst4 = conn.prepareStatement(sql4);

        pst4.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());

        pst4.setString(2, (String) comboMarket.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
        pst4.setString(3, txtLoanAmount.getText());
        pst4.setString(4, txtStart.getText());
        pst4.setString(5, txtDailyPay.getText());
        if(txtExpiry.getText().isEmpty())
            pst4.setString(6, null);
        else
            pst4.setString(6, txtExpiry.getText());
        pst4.execute();
        //  System.out.println("Nasave ang sql4 ? : "+ pst4.execute());

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }             
}
```

and for UPDATE

```
    cmdNewSpouse.setEnabled(false);
    String sql = "delete from tblClientInfo where ClientID = ?";

    try 
    {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");
        UpdateJTable();
        clear();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}                                      

    private void cmdUpdateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)          
    {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String sql = "update tblClientInfo set LastName = ?, FirstName = ?, MiddleName = ?,   Gender = ?, BirthPlace = ?, "
            + "BirthDate = ?, Status = ?, ResAddress = ?, EmploymentQuery = ?, HomeNo = ?,   ResidenceType = ?  "
            + "where ClientID = ?";

        String sql2 = "update tblBusinessInfo set StallNo = ?, "
            + "MarketID = ?, Location = ?, BusinessTelNo = ?, YearStarted = ?, "
            + "OtherBusinessQuery = ?, MonthlyIncome = ? , CarQuery = ?, CarBrand = ?, "
            + "MortgagedQuery = ?, PBalance = ? where tblBusinessInfo.ClientID = ?";

        String sql3 = "update tblBusinessSituation set MerchandiseID = ?, StockValue = ?, "
            + "LowestSale = ?, AverageSale = ? where tblBusinessSituation.ClientID = ?";

        String sql4 = "update tblledger set MarketID = ?, LoanAmount = ?, DateStarted = ?,   DailyPay = ?, Expiry = ? "
                + "where tblledger.ClientID = ?";
        try 
        {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            //===================================Client Information Layer=======================================
            pst.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtLastName.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txtFirstName.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtMiddleName.getText());  
            pst.setString(5, (String) comboGender.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(6, txtBirthPlace.getText());
            if(txtBirthDate.getText().isEmpty())
                pst.setString(7, null);
            else
                pst.setString(7, txtBirthDate.getText());
            pst.setString(8, (String) comboStatus.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.setString(9, txtAddress.getText());
            pst.setString(10, (String) comboEmploymentQuery.getSelectedItem().toString());
            if(txtHomeNo.getText().isEmpty())
                pst.setString(11, null);
            else
                pst.setString(11, txtHomeNo.getText());
            pst.setString(12, (String) comboResidency.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst.execute();
            //System.out.println("Nasave ang sql ? : "+pst.execute());

            UpdateJTable();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } 


        try
        {
            pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

            //===================================Buainess Information Layer======================================
            pst2.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
            pst2.setString(2, (String) comboMarket.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
            if(txtStallNo.getText().isEmpty())
                pst2.setString(3, null);

            else
                pst2.setString(3, txtStallNo.getText());
            pst2.setString(4, txtLocation.getText());
            if(txtBusinessNo.getText().isEmpty())
                pst2.setString(5, null);
            else
                pst2.setString(5, txtBusinessNo.getText());
            if(txtYearStarted.getText().isEmpty())
                pst2.setString(6, null);
            else
                pst2.setString(6, txtYearStarted.getText());
            pst2.setString(7, (String) comboOtherBusinessQuery.getSelectedItem().toString());
            if(txtMonthlyIncome.getText().isEmpty())
                pst.setString(8, null);
            else
                pst2.setString(8, txtMonthlyIncome.getText());
            pst2.setString(9, (String) comboCar.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pst2.setString(10, txtBrand.getText());
            pst2.setString(11, (String) comboMortgaged.getSelectedItem().toString());
            if(txtPBalance.getText().isEmpty())
                pst2.setString(12, null);
            else
                pst2.setString(12, txtPBalance.getText());
            pst2.execute();
            // System.out.println("Nasave ang sql2 ? : "+ pst2.execute());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

        try
        {
            pst3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);

            pst3.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());
            pst3.setString(2, (String) comboMerchandise.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
            if(txtValueOfStocks.getText().isEmpty())
                pst3.setString(3, null);
            else
                pst3.setString(3, txtValueOfStocks.getText());
            if(txtLowestSale.getText().isEmpty())
                pst3.setString(4, null);
            else
                pst3.setString(4, txtLowestSale.getText());
            if(txtAveSale.getText().isEmpty())
                pst3.setString(5, null);
            else
                pst3.setString(5, txtAveSale.getText());        
            pst3.execute();
            //System.out.println("Nasave ang sql3 ? : "+ pst3.execute());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);      
        }  

        try
        {  

            pst4 = conn.prepareStatement(sql4);

            pst4.setString(1, txtClientID.getText());

            pst4.setString(2, (String) comboMarket.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(0, 1));
            pst4.setString(3, txtLoanAmount.getText());
            pst4.setString(4, txtStart.getText());
            pst4.setString(5, txtDailyPay.getText());
            if(txtExpiry.getText().isEmpty())
                pst4.setString(6, null);
            else
                pst4.setString(6, txtExpiry.getText());
            pst4.execute();
            //  System.out.println("Nasave ang sql4 ? : "+ pst4.execute());

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }   
    }
                             `
```

thanks in advance for the future help.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is bit messy and large, as a suggestion please check the JTable refresh/validate and any propertyChange listeners methods.
After adding a new Entry in DB , a event must be transferred to the UI and then the JTable must be updated in the way the code is being written

Comment: this answer is not much better than the question, IMO ;-) The part I like least, is the _JTable_ refresh/validate/updated - that's wrong: what needs to be updated it the table's _tableModel_

Comment: I agree with you ...I missed the major point ... :) but I just wanted to explain in around affected scenarios of JTable, thanks for updating me